# the usb drivers for adb do not work for Motorola mc40

Tags: android, usb, drivers, motorola

1. I am running Windows 7 and Eclipse. Emulator runs great!
2. My Motorola MC40 has the Settings-Application->developer-> usb
   debugging box checked.
3. I use the drivers from
   https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481
4. The MC40 is not recognized
5. "abd devices" command shows no device attached.
6. The drivers in /sdk/extras/google/usb_drivers do not work.

I have searched everywhere and can't find an answer. I would really like to use my Android device with Eclipse. Any one out there have experience with Motorola MC class hand helds? Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly the same problem, using a Windows 7 Home, 64-bit laptop, and a Motorola Defy+ (MB526).

Comment: Any results on this? I have been asked to do some work on one.

Comment: Note that Motorola Mobility (recently owned by Google, now owned by Lenovo) is not the same company as Motorola Solutions, the maker of the MC40. As a result, the link to drivers above is not likely to be of much value. See the link info in the answer below for motorolasolutions.com.

Answer (score 2):

Hi android  developers   for motorola  Solutions  (Enterprice Edition devices )-

Download the  exe and install  as per the below link,  and then surely  adt will detect  the   Motorola device for  enterprise edition Android   such  as  ET1-Android Tablet ,MC 40 and TC55.

you can download this from [Motorola Solutions support site](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=95914) and search for **"Android USB driver"**.

Currently last version is 1.1 that covers ET1, MC40 and TC55.

Comment: New version available from May 2015, Version 2. Worked for me where 1.1 would not (Windows 7)   https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=99052

Answer (score 2):

I found this link, installed the windows drivers, and it worked perfectly.

https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481

Hope this helps some of you.

I can't find the link to credit the person you posted the link above...but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys! I found the solution.
You'll have to change original google ini & inf files from sdk and then reinstall the device. Here's manual:
https://docs.symbol.com/ReleaseNotes/MC40N0_ADB_Setup_Instruction.docx

Important note: my MC40, seems a bit different Vendor ID, so I had to change the GUIDs from the manual accordingly to those that I have found in my "Device Manager".

Comment: Yes, the actual protocol is pretty much standard across devices (excepting the recent change to authentication, but that's still not vendor-unique) so usually it's only the VID/PID that prevents you from using a generic driver with a vendor device.

Comment: Man, this isn't working for me. Strange! I've checked a couple times that my files are correct, but nothing. Any other thoughts?!

Comment: Some days this works for me but latly I've been having problems and it does not work. I find this rather strange.. everything is done as the doc says but it does not work. WIn7 thinks it's a portable disk without the MC40 being even set to usb storage. Debug is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

None of the instructions I could find online seemed to work but here's what I did.

1. Install the USB device drivers from the motorola website.
2. In device manager, Find the "MC40" device, and update it's drivers.
3. Select Browse my Computer
4. Then "Let me pick from a list of devices"
5. select ADB Interfaces->Motorola->Motorola Composite ADB Interface
6. Restart USB debugging if necessary

Comment: Thanks.  This worked for me except I chose ADB Interfaces->Google->Android ADB Interface

Comment: Had also problems with adb finding devices until I figured out adb needs to be ran with administrator rights. Just starting cmd with admin rights and 'adm kill-server' 'adm devices' works for me.

Comment: This problem came back, but when I did "kill-server" then "start-server" (instead of letting it autostart) from an administrative cmd prompt, it is now working again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working link to the driver.

https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=95914&productDetailGUID=f5563b1ca4151410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=a0bde8cea8151410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps anyone but I had an issue with the docking station. I plugged the micro USB directly into the device and I can now operate on it normally.

I also downloaded the drivers from this site.

https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=92183&productDetailGUID=d476e3883f840410VgnVCM10000081c7b10aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=2202caf8fb16e310VgnVCM1000000389bd0aRCRD

Comment: The docking station does not work at all. I can definitely confirm this. It seems to be charging only.